# Frog CMS and form textarea

Tags: forms, content-management-system, textarea

I have created form inside a template file. Form code looks like:

```
<div id="form" style="width: 170px;">
  <form method="post" action="">
    <p>Name (required)<br>
     <span><input type="text" size="25" value="" name="your-name"></span> </p>
     <p>Email (required)<br>
     <span><input type="text" size="25"  value="" name="your-email"></span> </p>
     <p>Phone <br>
     <span><input type="text" size="25" value="" name="Phone"></span></p>
     <p>Subject<br>
     <span><input type="text" size="25" value="" name="your-subject"></span> </p>
     <p>Message<br>
     <textarea rows="5" cols="18" name="your-message"></textarea></p>
     <p style="padding-left:12px;"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>            
</div>
```

Form looks properly under FireFox and Chrome but not IE.

Web site is based on Frog CMS 0.9.5
Link to it: http://www.rosica.com/services/form-test-page

Any clue what can be wrong for IE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have in ie.css file, class which make textarea bigger :

```
textarea {
..
    width:390px;
...
}
```

you can replace this, or if you need that class, you can overwrite with :

```
#column3 textarea {
    width:165px;
}
```

Comment: Great! Never expected that it will be in separate CSS related to the theme resolution (I'm not a big fan of Frog CMS). Too bad there is no IEBug like FireBug to examine what is going on.